# Spin connection in terms of the vielbein/tetrad and their derivatives

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

Mimicking the process for finding the Christoffel symbol in terms of the metric (and its derivatives), see box 17.4 on page 205 of [Moore's GR workbook](https://physicspages.com/pdf/Moore/Moore%20Problems%2017.04%20Box.pdf), we can use the torsion-free (gauge local translations curvature set to zero) condition and some non-trivial index gymnastics to solve for the spin connection in terms of the vielbein (and its derivatives).

The following [thesis](https://www.rug.nl/research/portal/files/34926446/Complete_thesis.pdf) outlines this. I include it here

[image]

I cannot get beyond the following with the first/algebraic Bianchi identity-like equation 2.54 of the thesis

$$
0 = R_{\mu\nu}{}^a e_{\rho a} + R_{\rho\mu}{}^a e_{\nu a} -R_{\nu\rho}{}^a e_{\mu a} $$

$$R_{\nu\rho}{}^a e_{\mu a} = R_{\mu\nu}{}^a e_{\rho a} + R_{\rho\mu}{}^a e_{\nu a}  $$

$$(\partial_{[\nu} e_{\rho]}{}^a - \omega_{[\nu}{}^{ab} e_{\rho]}{}_b) e_{\mu a} =(\partial_{[\mu} e_{\nu]}{}^a - \omega_{[\mu}{}^{ab} e_{\nu]}{}_b) e_{\rho a}+(\partial_{[\rho} e_{\mu]}{}^a - \omega_{[\rho}{}^{ab} e_{\mu]}{}_b) e_{\nu a} $$

$$
\partial_{[\nu} e_{\rho]}{}^a e_{\mu a} - \omega_{[\nu}{}^{ab} e_{\rho]}{}_b e_{\mu a} = \partial_{[\mu} e_{\nu]}{}^a e_{\rho a} - \omega_{[\mu}{}^{ab} e_{\nu]}{}_b e_{\rho a} + \partial_{[\rho} e_{\mu]}{}^a e_{\nu a} - \omega_{[\rho}{}^{ab} e_{\mu]}{}_b e_{\nu a}
$$

$$
\omega_{[\mu}{}^{ab} e_{\nu]}{}{}_b e_{\rho a} + \omega_{[\rho}{}^{ab} e_{\mu]}{}_b e_{\nu a} - \omega_{[\nu}{}^{ab} e_{\rho]}{}_b e_{\mu a} = \partial_{[\mu} e_{\nu]}{}^a e_{\rho a}  + \partial_{[\rho} e_{\mu]}{}^a e_{\nu a} - \partial_{[\nu} e_{\rho]}{}^a e_{\mu a}  
$$

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Torsion-less property reads:

$$
T_{abc}=(\nabla_{[a}e_{b]}^{m})e_{mc}=(e^{m}_{[a}\partial_{m}e_{b]}^{n})e_{nc}+\omega_{[ab]c}=0\
$$
which implies
$$
\omega_{[ab]c}=-(e^{m}_{[a}\partial_{m}e_{b]}^{n})e_{nc}
$$

The following identity will play a role:

$$
\omega_{abc}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\omega_{[ab]c}-\omega_{[bc]a}+\omega_{[ca]b}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(\omega_{a(bc)}+\omega_{b(ca)}-\omega_{c(ba)}\right)
$$
which holds for all objects with 3 indices. In order to see this identity just note that
$$
abc=bac+[ab]c=-bca+\{[ab]c\}+\{b(ac)\}=
$$
$$
=-cba+\{[ab]c-[bc]a\}+\{b(ac)\}=
$$
$$
=+cab+\{[ab]c-[bc]a\}+\{b(ac)-c(ba)\}=
$$
$$
=+acb+\{[ab]c-[bc]a+[ca]b\}+\{b(ac)-c(ba)\}=
$$
$$
=-abc+\{[ab]c-[bc]a+[ca]b\}+\{b(ac)-c(ba)+a(cb)\}
$$
with an important minus sign in front of $abc$ in the right-hand-side, allowing us to obtain a non-trivial equation
$$
2abc = \{[ab]c-[bc]a+[ca]b\}+\{a(bc)+b(ca)-c(ab)\}\,.
$$

Now $\omega_{a(bc)}=0$ since the structure group is Lorentz. We have
$$
\omega_{abc}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\omega_{[ab]c}-\omega_{[bc]a}+\omega_{[ca]b}\right)=
$$
$$
=-\frac{1}{2}(e^{m}_{[a}\partial_{m}e_{b]}^{n})e_{nc}+\frac{1}{2}(e^{m}_{[b}\partial_{m}e_{c]}^{n})e_{na}-\frac{1}{2}(e^{m}_{[c}\partial_{m}e_{a]}^{n})e_{nb}
$$
which means that $\omega_{abc}$ is fixed in terms of $e^{m}_{a}$ if $T_{abc}=0$. In general, for the structure group being Lorentz, we only need $T_{abc}$ to be given in order for $\omega_{abc}$ be fixed in terms of $e^{m}_{a}$.

Answer (score 0):

Although I cannot give the whole derivation here, I can give you a hint on how to find it easier. Here I'll follow the derivation Shapiro does in a review article called "Physical aspects of space-time torsion", and you can check his final formula (just adapting to your case in which torsion, and therefore contorsion too, vanishes, right?)

You can just start by noting that $\psi\gamma^\mu \psi$ is a vector and that the covariant derivative is linear and obeys the product rule. By noting this and using the format of the covariant derivative of a spinor as 
$$\nabla_\mu \psi = \partial_\mu \psi + \frac{i}{2} \omega_\mu^{ab}\sigma_{ab}\psi$$ you might arive at the expression for the spin connection in terms of the tetrad. If you want to check, it's the equation (2.32) in Shapiro's paper, and if you set null torsion then K = 0 in (2.31).
Technically it is in terms of the Christofell symbol, but you might be able to express it in terms of the vierbein.

Answer (score 0):

The legendary McKinsey-style answer always involves three points (sometimes they just conjure up a non-existing third point). Let me give it shot.

1. Firstly, is there a unique solution? It's a simple exercise of counting degrees of freedom: The torsion 2-form $T^a_{\mu\nu}$ has $4*6$ degree of freedom ($4$ from $a$ and 6 from 2-form anti-symmetric index $\mu\nu$), whereas the spin connection 1-form $\omega^{ab}_{\mu}$ has $6*4$ degree of freedom m($6$ from anti-symmetric $ab$ and 4 from 1-form index $\mu$). Given that $4*6 = 6*4$, the zero-torsion condition $T^a_{\mu\nu} = 0$ yields a unique solution for the spin connection $\omega^{ab}_{\mu}$.
2. Secondly, is there a formula for the unique solution? Yes, the spin connection can be expressed in term of vielbein and its derivative $\omega^{ab}_{\mu} = \omega (e, d e)$.
3. Thirdly (this is not McKinseyian padding), do I really need to know the exact formula $\omega (e, d e)$ to calculate the solution? Not really, for many instances we can just guess the solution and verify it via the zero torsion condition $T = de + e\omega + \omega e=0$, especially when highly symmetric spacetime is in concern. For example, the Minkowskian flat spacetime entails zero spin connection $\omega^{ab}_{\mu} =0$. And we know it's the only and correct answer, cf. point 1.